# Where do I put modular logic?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Node and Express and I have a very beginner question. In fact it's so basic that I'm having trouble coming up with a title for it. I'm writing a modular piece of logic. It involves a few javascript files and I'd like to keep them together in one directory.  When I person goes to my web app, this code is to be accessed from routes/index.js. I want to have something like

```
var foo = require('???/logic');
```

and then when somebody loads the page I will call

```
foo.getBar();
```

and then assign what it returns to a variable used in the jade template

So my questions are 1. Where should I put my directory of modular code? node_modules? and 2. Does this, generally, sound like the right way to design an express app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose from the structure below based on the amount of code we are talking about.

## A: single CommonJS module in a single .js file

- You can export functions, constructor functions, properties
- if you have 30 properties exported or more than X lines of code (for me X is 300ish, for others they are OK with 500ish), graduate to the next option

## B: CommonJS module directory consisting of a my-module/index.js and other supporting .js files

- other modules can require this with `require('./my-module')` and not know or care whether `my-module` is 1 .js file or many in a directory
- Use this variant as your logic grows
- loose coupling. High cohesion.

## C: Put your logic in it's own npm module

- This makes it shareable with the community and across your internal projects as well
- The better you get at this and more comfortable with the process and tools, the more likely you are to skip **A** and **B** and just make standalone npm modules